Is this an equivalent statement and satisfactory proof of Euler's Rotation Theorem?
Euler's original theorem.

In whatever way a sphere is turned about its centre, it is always
possible to assign a diameter, whose direction in the translated state
agrees with that of the initial state.


My proposed equivalent theorem: The geodesics normal through the midpoints of the geodesic displacement
arcs of any two mutually orthogonal diameters intersect on a uniquely
determined axis of rotation, except in two cases:

The identity transformation, which allows every diameter to be an axis of rotation.
The axis of rotation lies in the plane spanned by those diameters. In that case it is always possible to find a suitable alternative pair of diameters to uniquely determine an axis of rotation

The essence of the theorem is clearly evident when we observe that the rotation of an orthogonal triple of unit arrows traces out three parallel circles centered on the same axis. Geodesics drawn normal to those circles intersect on the axis of rotation.  It only requires two of the arrows to fully determine the configuration of the sphere.
Proof: For simplicity we consider the unit sphere, and denote unit
arrows from the center to a point on the sphere using the notation
$\hat{\mathfrak{p}}.$ All circles under discussion lie on the sphere.
All planes are through the origin.

First consider a displacement $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o}\mapsto\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{\bullet}.$
The largest circle sharing this displacement pair is the geodesic
whose axis of symmetry is generated by $\hat{\mathfrak{n}}$ which
is normal to both $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o}$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{\bullet}.$
The smallest circle sharing the pair is centered at the midpoint $\mathfrak{m}=\left(\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{\bullet}+\mathfrak{\hat{\mathfrak{p}}}_{o}\right)/2.$ of
the cord from $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o}$ to $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{\bullet}.$
All other circles sharing the pair are centered on a point in the
plane $\mathcal{P}$ spanned by $\hat{\mathfrak{n}}$ and $\mathfrak{m}.$
Thus every candidate axis of rotation for $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o}\mapsto\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{\bullet}$
lies in $\mathcal{P}.$ Clearly a geodesic normal to the geodesic
displacement arc through the midpoint $\hat{\mathfrak{m}}=\mathfrak{m}/\left\Vert \mathfrak{m}\right\Vert $
will intersect every candidate axis of rotation.
Now, let $\hat{\mathfrak{q}}_{o}\perp\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o}$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{q}}_{o}\mapsto\hat{\mathfrak{q}}_{\bullet}$
be produced by the same transformation producing $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o}\mapsto\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{\bullet}.$
Obviously there will be an analogous plane $\mathcal{Q}$ holding
candidate axes for this displacement pair, and an analogous normal
geodesic lying in that plane. The intersection $\mathcal{P}\bigcap\mathcal{Q}$
is the unique axis of rotation producing both $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o}\mapsto\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{\bullet}$
and $\hat{\mathfrak{q}}_{o}\mapsto\hat{\mathfrak{q}}_{\bullet}.$
If $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o},\hat{\mathfrak{q}}_{o},$ and the axis of rotation are co-planer then either one of these diameters is the axis of rotation, or the normal geodesics coincide.  In the latter case we can replace one of the diameters with the one normal to both $\hat{\mathfrak{p}}_{o}$ and $\hat{\mathfrak{q}}_{o}.$

You are correct.  I will fix that when I get a chance. Thank you.
